# Get Hebrew day-in-month as text

Tags: swift, calendar, hebrew

In the Hebrew calendar, the days in the month are text.

For example, the first in "Sivan" (name of a month) is written "א" in Hebrew (and not "1" like in the Gregorian calendar).
This is my code:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .hebrew)
formatter.dateFormat = "d"
print(formatter.string(from: date)) // "1"
```

But unfortunately, instead of getting `א` I'm getting `1`.

I wanted to know if there's a way to get it as it should have been? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I initially thought it was just a matter of setting `Locale` on the `DateFormatter`, but turns out a date style was also needed to be set:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .hebrew)

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "he") // <- this
formatter.dateStyle = .short                // <- and this

formatter.dateFormat = "dd"                 // after dateStyle

print(formatter.string(from: Date())) // כ״ט
```